How to get the maven-compiler-plugin to use additional classes directories
We are attempting to use the Eclipse Transformer plugin to deal with some dependencies that use "javax" packages, and which now need to use "jakarta" packages.  The Eclipse Transformer plugin works ok from the command line to transform classes, and the "jar" goal of this plugin does appear to generate transformed classes in the target directory, but what I don't understand is how to configure the maven-compiler-plugin to now use those generated classes instead of the original classes in the artifact.
For instance, this example: https://github.com/OmniFish-EE/upgrading-jakarta-ee-applications/blob/main/javax-jakarta-transform-individual-deps/pom.xml , shows it processing several dependencies, dumping the transformed classes into "target/transformed".  In this example, it simply includes the transformed classes in the WAR, but in our situation, we need to use those transformed classes at compile time.
To show some actual code from our pom, this is a slightly elided excerpt, showing what I currently have for the transformer plugin, specifying two dependencies to be converted:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
    <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/transformed</buildDirectory>
        <rules>
            <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>transform-ccp</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifact>
                    <groupId>com.att.example.csi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>csi_v278_CustomerCareProfile</artifactId>
                    <version>278.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
                <baseName>csi_v278_CustomerCareProfile</baseName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>transform-schema</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifact>
                    <groupId>com.example.csi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>csi_v116_schema</artifactId>
                    <version>116.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
                <baseName>csi_v116_schema</baseName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

Notice that this using the "generate-sources" phase, so these transformed classes will be available at compile time. This does create two jar files in target/transformed, but I'm not sure what to do with them at this point. I have to ensure that these jars are used at compile time, instead of the original jars for the two dependencies.

I think I've found a solution for this. The key is to use the ant-run-plugin to extract the transformed jar files into target/classes. In this particular test case, there were other problems unrelated to this, so I'm not 100% certain this fixed everything, but it looks pretty likely.
